# Adding a secondary/backup LDAP server in ruby-ldap

Tags: ruby, ldap

There are lots of examples out there about how to open and use a Ruby/LDAP connection. I do *not* see any documentation or examples about opening a connection to one LDAP server and automatically falling back to a secondary/backup LDAP server. For instance, I have this:

```
ldap_port = LDAP::LDAP_PORT
ldap_scope = LDAP::LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE
ldap = LDAP::Conn.new(host1, ldap_port)
```

Does Ruby/LDAP have anything like

`ldap.secondary(host2, ldap_port)`

or am I going to have to do this manually with a begin/rescue/end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the best way would be with a rescue

```
ldap_port = LDAP::LDAP_PORT
ldap_scope = LDAP::LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE
begin  
ldap = LDAP::Conn.new(host1, ldap_port)
rescue LDAP::Error
ldap = LDAP::Conn.new(host2, ldap_port)
end
```

somehting like that

Comment: Thanks; so do you know for certain that there is no such thing as a built-in "secondary"?

Comment: i dont know for certain, no but you can check the documentation http://ruby-ldap.sourceforge.net/rdoc/ but the way its set up just using a string for the hostname makes me think its not, can you select the check if you like my answer / vote it up :D

Comment: I would have liked a more definitive yes/no, but there's only one reply here for a year, so I can't be picky.

Comment: yeah sorry, hope what i have is of some help, haven't messed with that in a while